# Spark: How to skip second condition in OR construction

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I try to check OR condition in Spark where function, the second condition is executed even thought first condition is true.

How can I skip the check of second condition?

```
df.
...
.where(
  (
    lit(lastLoadingDate).isNull
    .or(
         col(srcDTTM) > lastLoadingDate.format(formatterDTTM)
       )
  )
  && col(SrcDTTM) <= currentLoadingDate.format(formatterDTTM)
)
```

I tried even check next expression:

```
df.
...
.where(
  (
    lit(true)
    .or(
         col(srcDTTM) > lastLoadingDate.format(formatterDTTM)
       )
  )
  && col(SrcDTTM) <= currentLoadingDate.format(formatterDTTM)
)
```

But second condition:

`col(srcDTTM) > lastLoadingDate.format(formatterDTTM)`

is always executed.

Comment: What do you mean by "_is always executed_"?

Answer (score 0):

Skip the check of second condition may result in incomplete data, because it is `or` judgment. If the **second condition is true** and **the first condition is false**, the amount of data in the result set will increase.

Comment: But if first condition is true, Why check second condition? isn't it redundant? I need skip second condition when first is true. Can I make like that? Or maybe is there other way to check variable on Null value before to perform format function.

Comment: You can try a logic similar to the following: ```case when cond1 then result1 when cond2 then result2 end```. When ```cond1``` is true, it will not enter ```cond2```, otherwise it will enter ```cond2```.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the second condition in OR judgement wont make any difference when the first condition is true. Assume adding another condition or using any other function to skip the second condition check. If first check is false then condition to check if first one is true or false and then going to the second part of OR judgement. It will be like 3 conditions instead of 2. Its better to use OR judgement as it is.